Import statements are "hiding" my js functions, What am I doing wrong?
The function uploadToBucket can no longer be referenced or found when adding the imports.
import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client, GetObjectCommand, ListObjectsV2Command } from ("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
import { getSignedUrl, S3RequestPresigner } from ("aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner");
import {axios} from ("axios");


    // Upload a file to Amazon S3
    async function uploadToBucket(options){
        
        console.log("[RingCentral App Server] Options are ", options);

        try {
            console.log("[RingCentral App Server] Starting cloud upload...");

            const start = Date.now();
            let s3Client;

            // Depending on the cloudProvider, set up the S3 client configuration
            if (options.cloudProvider === "AWS") {
                console.log("[RingCentral App Server] Configuring for AWS S3...");
                s3Client = new S3Client({
                    region: options.iparams.recordingBucketRegionAWS,
                    credentials: {
                        accessKeyId: options.iparams.recordingBucketAccessKey,
                        secretAccessKey: options.iparams.recordingBucketSecretKey,
                    },
                });

            } else if (options.cloudProvider === "GCS") {
                console.log("[RingCentral App Server] Configuring for Google Cloud...");
                s3Client = new S3Client({
                    region: options.iparams.recordingBucketRegionGC,
                    endpoint: "https://storage.googleapis.com",
                    credentials: {
                        accessKeyId: options.iparams.recordingBucketAccessKey,
                        secretAccessKey: options.iparams.recordingBucketSecretKey,
                    },
                });
            }

            console.log("[RingCentral App Server] Fetching the recording data...");
            const recordingResponse = await axios.get(options.recordingUri, {
                decompress: false,
                responseType: "arraybuffer",
            });

            console.log('[RingCentral App Server] Received recording response.', recordingResponse);

            const recordingFile = recordingResponse.data;

            console.log("[RingCentral App Server] Generating a random ID for the file key...");

            // Created at: createRecordingInfoObject(contactid) -> recording-{contactId}-{mmss}-{yyyyMMdd}.mp3
            const key = options.fileName;
            console.log(`[RingCentral App Server] Generated key for file: ${key}`);

            console.log("[RingCentral App Server] Sending upload command...");

            const command = new PutObjectCommand({ Bucket: options.iparams.recordingBucketName, Key: key });
            let signedUri = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
            let resp = await axios.put(signedUri, recordingFile);

            console.log("[RingCentral App Server] Response from uploading recording file: ", resp);
            console.log("[RingCentral App Server] File uploaded successfully!");

            const end = Date.now();

            console.log(`[RingCentral App Server] Execution time: ${end - start} ms`);
            console.log("[RingCentral App Server] Cloud upload completed successfully.");

         //   renderData(null, "Cloud upload completed successfully");

        } catch (err) {
            console.error("[RingCentral App Server] Error encountered during cloud upload:", err);
          //  renderData(err);
       }
    }

Aside from that I am also receivin g the following error when loading the JS file in our browser app:
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:10001/iframe/agent/scripts/openai/bucketHelper.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
I do not know what is going wrong because I thought you could use import statements like this.
I have tried to use required and scripts refences in the html but it did not work.

You are not using uploadToBucket anywhere. If you want to use it from html you have to assign it to window. window. uploadToBucket = uploadToBucket. The mime type error suggest that the path is wrong

Please also show the html file where you try to include this script
